# Referencing objects in XAML design data

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

How can I reference the same object twice (or more often) in a XAML design data file?
I tried to use `{x:Reference}`, but this does not seem to work.

Here is an example:

The combo box in the cells of the second column of the sample's data grid displays a list of "data types". The list of available data types comes from the `Types` property of the main window's view model (= the data context). The list of items in the grid comes from the `Items` property of the view model. Each item has a `Name` and a `Type` column, where Type references a data type object.

The sample grid looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the XAML design data which should show the same grid contents in the Visual Studio designer (but it doesn't):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:MainWindowViewModel
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridSample"
    >
    <local:MainWindowViewModel.Types>
        <local:DataType Name="String" x:Name="String"/>
        <local:DataType Name="Integer" x:Name="Integer"/>
    </local:MainWindowViewModel.Types>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel.Items>
        <local:Item Name="Lorem" Type="{x:Reference String}"/>
        <local:Item Name="Ipsum" Type="{x:Reference Integer}"/>
    </local:MainWindowViewModel.Items>
</local:MainWindowViewModel>
```

Above, I am using `{x:Reference String}` to obtain a reference to the object that was created by `<local:DataType Name="String" x:Name="String"/>`.

In the Visual Studio designer, the list is empty, and the error message "Errors found in markup: ... DesignData.xaml" is displayed. In the editor for the design data XAML files, I get the error message "Service provider is missing the INameResolver service".

Is there any alternative to `{x:Reference}` which I could use in design data files to refer to an object?

For completeness, here are the remaining files of my sample:

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="DataGridSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sample" Height="300" Width="400"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=DesignData.xaml}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="types" Source="{Binding Types}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource types}}" 
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                        Header="Type" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DataGridSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DataGridSample
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<DataType> _dataTypes;
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            DataType typeString = new DataType {Name = "String"};
            DataType typeInteger = new DataType {Name = "Integer"};

            _dataTypes = new ObservableCollection<DataType> {typeString, typeInteger};
            _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
                {
                    new Item {Name = "Lorem", Type = typeString},
                    new Item {Name = "Ipsum", Type = typeInteger}
                };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DataType> Types
        {
            get
            {
                return _dataTypes;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DataType Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x:Reference` only works with the `Name` of `FrameworkElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Background on why `x:Reference` doesn't work .....

`x:Reference` is a XAML 2009 feature.

You can't use `x:Reference` in XAML markup that is compiled according to the MSDN docs.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx

It's designed for loose XAML...e.g. if you create a XAML Page (.xaml) and load it via Internet Explorer.

When you use DesignData the Designer effectively creates and compiles a new class whose shape and content is as described in your DesignData file.

There's no support for it in Visual Studio/Blend Designers.

- http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/12/XAML-2009-Future

Here's a counter argument.

> Here is the explanation from Adam Nathan's WPF 4 unleashed book:  "The
>   x:Reference markup extension is often mistakenly associated with the
>   XAML2009  features that can only be used from loose XAML at the time
>   of this writing. Although  x:Reference is a new feature in WPF 4, it
>   can be used from XAML2006 just fine as long as your project is
>   targeting version 4 or later of the .NET Framework.  One glitch is
>   that the XAML designer in Visual Studio 2010 doesnâ��t properly handle
>   x:Reference, so it gives the following design-time error that you can
>   safely ignore:  Service provider is missing the INameResolver service"

- http://wpftutorial.net/XAML2009.html

Workaround solution ...

Comment: I know that I cannot use `{x:Reference}`; that is what I wrote above. In case it did not become clear, I repeat the original question: "Is there any alternative to `{x:Reference}` which I could use in design data files to refer to an object?" (And by the way: XAML design data files are not compiled.)